# Open settings of X network adapter from CMD/BAT

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter, cmd.exe, runas

How to open setting of the specific network adapter via commandline in Windows 7 Enterprise? 
I'm under domain user but also have access to local administator user. 
Under domain user I have no rights to do this (to open this settings tab) and want to do this like RUNAS in order to avoid secondary login.
I tried

```
ncpa.cpl
```

but this opens list of adapters whereas I want to open settings of specific adapter

Comment: If you say what you want to do in that dialog maybe you could do it with other commands too (like `netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static ipaddr subnetmask gateway metric` for instance which you could run with `runas`)

Comment: Okay, I know about netsh. But open the dialog itself is not possible?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. But how about opening `ncpa.cpl` as another user? Just do `runas /user:you_local_admin_user ncpa.cpl`. Would that work?

Comment: Mmmm, on one machine i got an error that `ncpa.cpl` is not a valid Win32 App. However `runas /u:you_local_admin_user "cmd /c ncpa.cpl"` worked ok. You could make a shortcut or (doskey) alias for that.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is your friend.

1. Start -> Type 'Powershell' -> Right Click -> Run As Administrator
2. Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
3. Run the following. The last line here is piping to gm (Get-Member), and that shows you some of what you can do here.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapter | ?{$_.Name -like 'Ethernet'} | ft -a

Name     InterfaceDescription               ifIndex Status MacAddress        LinkSpeed
----     --------------------               ------- ------ ----------        ---------
Ethernet Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller      15 Up     D8-CB-8A-66-87-BC    1 Gbps

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 15 | ft -a

Name     InterfaceDescription               ifIndex Status MacAddress        LinkSpeed
----     --------------------               ------- ------ ----------        ---------
Ethernet Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller      15 Up     D8-CB-8A-66-87-BC    1 Gbps

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $na = Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 15
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $na | gm
```

Comment: Well, it lists adapter properties, but the aim was slightly another one - to view and **to edit** adapter settings. How can I edit the settings with your approach?